# how to get associated marker object for a infowindow in google maps api v3 with multiple infowindows

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have a google map on my page, i am displaying multiple markers on my map with infowindow attached to each marker, when i click on a marker its related infowindow opens & displays information for the marker.

I have a button in infowindow which updates related status of marker & upon update i change the markericon.

So, how do i get exact marker object of infowindow in which the button is clicked.

Note that there may multiple infowindows open at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: Some code may help us help you.

Comment: When you create the infowindows (in a loop presumably), set `infoWindow.marker = marker`, thus giving you a mechanism to refer back from the infoWindow to its marker.

Answer (score 2):

to get marker which was clicked, you should use **infoWindow.anchor**